# How to use async lambda with SelectMany?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects

I'm getting the following error when trying to use an `async` lambda within `IEnumerable.SelectMany`:

```
var result = myEnumerable.SelectMany(async (c) => await Functions.GetDataAsync(c.Id));
```

> The type arguments for method 'IEnumerable
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectMany(this
>   IEnumerable, Func>)' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Where `GetDataAsync` is defined as:

```
public interface IFunctions {
    Task<IEnumerable<DataItem>> GetDataAsync(string itemId);
}

public class Functions : IFunctions {
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DataItem>> GetDataAsync(string itemId) {
        // return await httpCall();
    }
}
```

I guess because my `GetDataAsync` method actually returns a `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`. But why does `Select` work, surely it should throw the same error?

```
var result = myEnumerable.Select(async (c) => await Functions.GetDataAsync(c.Id));
```

Is there any way around this?

Comment: can you provide declaration for `Functions.GetDataAsync`?

Comment: @Grundy `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`, but I've added the full declaration to the question. Where `T` is different than the type of `myEnumerable`

Comment: @HimBromBeere, select return _collection of collection_, but i think OP need simple collection

Comment: But `GetDataAsnyc` does not return an enumeration but a `Task`.

Comment: First of all, Your assumption is right. if your method returns Task<T>, await converts it to **T**. So return type is not the problem. But I really did not get why are you using SelectMany? You don't have something like **list of list** ?

Comment: That's a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), asking about your attempted solution, not the actual problem. *What* are you trying to execute in parallel? Paralled db calls typically slow performance, they don't increase it. Why not PLINQ anyway? Or `await Task.WhenAll()` on the IEnumerable<Task>`? No reason to await inside `Select`

Comment: @ozgur This is only partly correct. The await "converts" the `Task<T>` to `T`, but since it's an async lambda it returns a `Task<T>` again, much like a normal async function would. The return type is the problem because it is `Task<IEnumerable<DataItem>>`.

Comment: If you want to retrieve multiple objects, just write the proper query for your ORM/data layer that returns data for a list of IDs. It will be *much* faster than multiple individual queries - you pay the network cost only once while selecting over a range of IDs is trivial.

Comment: This is a HTTP request using linq-to-objects to format my code nicely, no data layers involved. @AsadSaeeduddin Perhaps my question is a poor reproduction - there is an IoC container in play here injecting `Functions` into my class. `myEnumerable` is simply `IEnumable<T>` which hopefully is irrelevant as I know my business logic is correct.

Comment: @RGraham, possibly you can change `Task<IEnumerable<DataItem>>` to `IEnumerable<Task<DataItem>>`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

async lambda expression cannot be converted to simple `Func<TSource, TResult>`.

So, select many cannot be used. You can run in synchronized context:

```
myEnumerable.Select(c => Functions.GetDataAsync(c.Id)).SelectMany(task => task.Result);
```

or

```
List<DataItem> result = new List<DataItem>();

foreach (var ele in myEnumerable)
{
    result.AddRange(await Functions.GetDataAsyncDo(ele.Id));
}
```

You cannot neither use `yield return` - it is by design. f.e.:

```
public async Task<IEnuemrable<DataItem>> Do() 
{
    ...
    foreach (var ele in await Functions.GetDataAsyncDo(ele.Id)) 
    {
        yield return ele; // compile time error, async method 
                          // cannot be used with yield return
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used `.Result` instead of `await` to make the call syncrhronous and all is well

Comment: Downvote was probably due to the use of `.Result` which may [cause deadlocks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Answer (score 62):

This is an extension:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T1>> SelectManyAsync<T, T1>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, Func<T, Task<IEnumerable<T1>>> func)
{
    return (await Task.WhenAll(enumeration.Select(func))).SelectMany(s => s);
}
```

That allows you to run:

```
var result = await myEnumerable.SelectManyAsync(c => Functions.GetDataAsync(c.Id));
```

Explanation: you have a list of tasks, each returns `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`. So you need to fire them all, then await all, and then squash the result via SelectMany.

Comment: One advantage of having this extracted to a method, rather than having it inline in your code, is that the extension returns a `Task<T>` so this can be awaited at a later place in the code.

Comment: Be aware that this parallelizes all calls to OP's `GetDataAsync(...)`. Usually that's a good thing, but might not be desired in certain scenarios.

Comment: Depending on your general use case, you might need to change the second parameter of the extension to be of type `Func<T, Task<List<T1>>>`.

Answer (score 10):

`Select` works because it will return an `IEnumerable<Task<T>>`, which can then be awaited with e.g. `Task.WhenAll`.

So, an easy workaround to this problem is:

```
IEnumerable<Task<IEnumerable<T>>> tasks = source.Select(GetNestedEnumerableTask);
IEnumerable<T>[] nestedResults = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
IEnumerable<T> results = nestedResults.SelectMany(nr => nr);
```

Answer (score 5):

With C#8 and `IAsyncEnumerable` we can write this more naturally:

```
public static async IAsyncEnumerable<R> SelectManyAsync<T, R>(this IEnumerable<T> ts, 
                                                    Func<T, Task<IEnumerable<R>>> func)
{
    foreach (var t in ts)
    {
        var rs = await func(t);
        foreach (var r in rs)
            yield return r;
    }
}
```

Note:
Use `await foreach(...` to iterate over an `IAsyncEnumerable`

Comment: This solution has the possible benefit of lazy sequential enumeration vs other approaches using `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: await foreach, not async foreach :)