# async SelectMany() extension method cannot infer type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asynchronous

I'm struggling to wrap my brain around type inference within an asynchronous extension method I've adopted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35874937/2835541).

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
  public static async Task<IEnumerable<T1>> SelectAsync<T, T1>(
    this IEnumerable<T> enumeration,
    Func<T, Task<T1>> func)
  {
    return await Task.WhenAll(enumeration.Select(func));
  }

  public static async Task<IEnumerable<T1>> SelectManyAsync<T, T1>(
    this IEnumerable<T> enumeration,
    Func<T, Task<IEnumerable<T1>>> func)
  {
    return (await enumeration.SelectAsync(func)).SelectMany(x => x);
  }
}
```

I'm making use of the extension methods as follows:

```
var allChildren = await parents.SelectManyAsync(parent => ReturnsChildrenAsync(parent));
```

`parents` is of type `IList<Parent>`

`ReturnsChildrenAsync()` returns a `Task<IList<Child>>`

But I'm getting the following error:

> The type arguments for method 'EnumerableExtensions.SelectManyAsync<T, T1>(IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, Task<IEnumerable<T1>>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

**It seems that `T1` cannot be inferred. Why can't this be derived from `Task<IList<Child>>`?**

Comment: Because `Task<IList<Child>>` != `Task<IEnumerable<Child>>`?

Comment: Doesn't `IList` implement `IEnumerable` though?

Comment: You should await `ReturnsChildrenAsync` in the lambda expression.

Comment: @CodeCaster You're right, when changing to use `Func<T, Task<IList<T1>>> func` it works. Is there a way of inferring the nested type arg when dealing with interfaces like this?

Comment: @GertArnold `ReturnsChildrenAsync` needs to return a task as the `Task.WhenAll` handles the await, at least that's how I'm understanding it.

Comment: When you change the return of `ReturnsChildrenAsync()` to `Task<IEnumerable<Child>>` it also works. Seems kind of cleaner.

Comment: @bommelding Unfortunately `ReturnsChildrenAsync()` refers to a library method outside of my control. I believe the root issue here is that an `IList` can't be inferred as an `IEnumerable`, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: Well, find one of those Eric Lippert answers with tigers and giraffes about co- and contravariance.

Comment: Could you try try `SelectManyAsync<Parent, Child>`?

Comment: I think the issue is that `Task<>` was written before [Variance in Generic Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/variance-in-generic-interfaces) was added in .Net 4, it simply isn't in the framework. You could open a bug.