# C#/Linq How to get all records by ParentId and then by FolderId recursively

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following setup for a table:

[image]

I need to obtain all the folders tied to a certain `ParentId` (only the direct children)
I also need to be able to pass in a `FolderId` and then obtain the full path of records to get to that `FolderId` starting at the top level (null parent id)

I've tried `.SelectMany()`, but I have this error:

**The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.SelectMany<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable, Func<TSource, IEnumerable>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly**

```
        public async Task<IList<FolderDTO>> GetFullPathByFolderId(int? parentId, bool onlyDirectChildren)
        {
            var allFolders = await GetAllFolders(false).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return allFolders.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId)
            .Union(allFolders.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId)
                        .SelectMany(y => GetFullPathByFolderId(y.FolderId)));

        }
```

So if `ParentId` of null is passed in I need to return 4 records: Folder names, in order: Private, Public, Shared, Private Deleted.

If `FolderId` is passed I need to return 2 records: Folder Names, in order: Untitled Directory, Public.

Is there a way to combine this into one or two methods?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Folders](
    [FolderId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL,
    [FolderName] [varchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [FolderTypeId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsHidden] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [DateModified] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DateSoftDeleted] [datetime] NULL,
    [SoftDeletedBy] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Folders] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [FolderId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**UPDATED CODE:**

Here is some code.

I would want to pass in `FolderId` `1` into the LINQ/C# Call and return the names: **Private** and **Private1**

```
    namespace App
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// FolderTypeDTO
        /// </summary>
        public class FolderTypeDTO
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the folder type identifier.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The folder type identifier.
            /// </value>
            public int FolderTypeId { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the name of the folder type.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The name of the folder type.
            /// </value>
            public string FolderTypeName { get; set; }
        }
    }
    
    namespace App
    {
        using System;
    
        /// <summary>
        /// Folder DTO
        /// </summary>
        public class FolderDTO
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the folder identifier.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The folder identifier.
            /// </value>
            public int FolderId { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the parent identifier.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The parent identifier.
            /// </value>
            public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance has sub folders.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            ///   <c>true</c> if this instance has sub folders; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
            /// </value>
            public bool HasSubFolders { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the name of the folder parent.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The name of the folder parent.
            /// </value>
            public string FolderParentName { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the name of the folder.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The name of the folder.
            /// </value>
            public string FolderName { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the folder type identifier.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The folder type identifier.
            /// </value>
            public int FolderTypeId { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the name of the folder type.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The name of the folder type.
            /// </value>
            public string FolderTypeName { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is hidden.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            ///   <c>true</c> if this instance is hidden; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
            /// </value>
            public bool IsHidden { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the level.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The level.
            /// </value>
            public int Level { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the date modified.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The date modified.
            /// </value>
            public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the modified by.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The modified by.
            /// </value>
            public int ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the name of the modified by.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The name of the modified by.
            /// </value>
            public string ModifiedByName { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the date soft deleted.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The date soft deleted.
            /// </value>
            public DateTime? DateSoftDeleted { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the soft deleted by.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The soft deleted by.
            /// </value>
            public int? SoftDeletedBy { get; set; }
    
            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the name of the soft deleted by.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>
            /// The name of the soft deleted by.
            /// </value>
            public string SoftDeletedByName { get; set; }
        }
    }

       var folderTypeList = new List<FolderTypeDTO>
        {
            new FolderTypeDTO
            {
                FolderTypeId = 1,
                FolderTypeName = "Private"
            },
            new FolderTypeDTO
            {
                FolderTypeId = 2,
                FolderTypeName = "Public"
            },
            new FolderTypeDTO
            {
                FolderTypeId = 3,
                FolderTypeName = "Shared"
            },
        };
    
        var folderList = new List<FolderDTO>
        {
            new FolderDTO
            {
                FolderId = 1,
                ParentId = null,
                FolderName = "Private",
                FolderTypeId = 1,
                IsHidden = false,
                DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ModifiedBy = 107 // my user id in our app
            },
            new FolderDTO
            {
                FolderId = 2,
                ParentId = null,
                FolderName = "Public",
                FolderTypeId = 2,
                IsHidden = false,
                DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ModifiedBy = 107 // my user id in our app
            },
            new FolderDTO
            {
                FolderId = 3,
                ParentId = 1,
                FolderName = "Private 1",
                FolderTypeId = 1,
                IsHidden = false,
                DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow,
                ModifiedBy = 107 // my user id in our app
            }
        };
```

Comment: What is `GetFullPathByFolderId`?

Comment: It suppose to be itself: GetAllFoldersByFolderId(y.FolderId)

Comment: Probably just need to `await` the call to `GetFullPathByFolderId()`. Right now you're trying to enumerate a task, which is not enumerable of course.

Comment: @JohnWu: that did not work :-( Same error message.

Comment: @ttaylor27272727 - Is there any chance that you could give us the source data in valid C# code?

Comment: @Enigmativity: What do you mean source code? Like the DTOs? I'm looking for the correct LINQ to pull the records out of the database recursively.

Comment: I would like data to work with to produce an answer. Can you please post the equivalent C# code (i.e. `var records = new [] { new { folderId = 1, partendId = (int?)null. /* etc */ }. /* etc */ };` for the data in your database so that we can have some valid data to play with?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Yes, let me try to set something up. Give me a few.

Comment: @Enigmativity: I added an "Update" item with some code. Let me know if that helps?

Comment: see the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495617/how-to-use-async-lambda-with-selectmany

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use async lambda with SelectMany?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33495617/how-to-use-async-lambda-with-selectmany)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the code. It's now easy to get a result.

Start with a lookup that will help generate a recursive set of `FolderDTO` objects by `parentID`.

```
ILookup<int?, FolderDTO> lookup = folderList.ToLookup(x => x.ParentId);
```

Now we can write a recursive method to return the full set of `FolderDTO` objects with the provided `parentID`.

```
IEnumerable<FolderDTO> GetHierarchically(int? parentId) =>
    from x in lookup[parentId]
    from y in GetHierarchically(x.FolderId).StartWith(x)
    select y;
```

Now it's a fairly simple case of doing a `Concat` and a `Join` to get the results you need.

```
IEnumerable<string> GetFolderNamesHierarchicallyByIdAndType(int parentId, string folderTypeName) =>
    from x in
        Enumerable
            .Concat(
                folderList.Where(f => f.FolderId == parentId),
                GetHierarchically(parentId))
    join y in folderTypeList on x.FolderTypeId equals y.FolderTypeId
    where y.FolderTypeName == folderTypeName
    select x.FolderName;
```

This can be called like this:

```
string[] names = GetFolderNamesHierarchicallyByIdAndType(1, "Private").ToArray();
```

The results I get from your sample data are:

```
Private 
Private 1
```

Comment: @Eigmativity: thank you so much! This is a great example and will teach me more!